# How to set the orientation of the views underneath the Gesture Overlay to "none"

Tags: android, xml, gesture

I am trying to set the orientation of the views underneath the GestureOverlay to none. At this point I am able to set the orientation to either vertical or horizontal. However, for my application I dont want either, this needs to be set to none.

In the [article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html) for gestures API, it says the following:

> orientation: indicates the scroll
> orientation of the views underneath.
> In this case the list scrolls
> vertically, which means that any
> horizontal gestures (like
> action_delete) can immediately be
> recognized as a gesture. Gestures that
> start with a vertical stroke must
> contain at least one horizontal
> component to be recognized. In other
> words, a simple vertical line cannot
> be recognized as a gesture since it
> would conflict with the list's
> scrolling.

And above that it shows this piece of code, displaying the android:orientation as vertical.

```
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gestures"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

After searching online I found this piece of code for an Android Theme that uses [android:orientation="none"](http://forum.samdroid.net/f57/honeygreen-theme-4743/index11.html)

So I tried to implement this into my GestureOverlay, however when I use this it just produces this error in the XML file: *error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'orientation' with value 'none').* My code is shown below:

```
    <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
android:id="@+id/gestures_alpha"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1.0"
android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
android:fadeOffset="2000"
android:orientation="none"/>
```

Could someone let me know if there is a work around, or if this is a SDK version problem. I am coding using SDK version 7 (2.1.1).

Thanks

Comment: I found some more information [here](http://gitorious.org/replicant/android_frameworks_base/commit/d98418db26a3af03d3c981efe3c4d5f6215327be) 
I dont know how this code works though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `android:orientation="none"` option is part of the [Replicant project](http://replicant.us/about/) and isn't valid for standard Android builds. In short, the only options you have are horizontal and vertical, sorry.

Comment: Thats unfortunate, i was hoping there would be some sort of workaround. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're trying have both horizontal and vertical gestures being recognized using GestureOverlayView. This is the solution:

```
gestureOverlayView.setOrientation(GestureOverlayView.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
gestureOverlayView.setGestureStrokeAngleThreshold(90);
```